# How to VLOOKUP with filtered results

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xzzHT7VjG24UJ4ZXaiZWsfzroTpn7jCJLexuTOf6SQs/edit?usp=sharing

Formula: `CashDiscounts!A1`

I'm trying to compare Discounted check #'s in `Discounts!B:B` to Cash Payments in `CashPayments!A:A`, sorted by User & Check #.  Basically wanting the `Discounts` sheet duplicated and trimmed down to only check #'s that match to `CashPayments`.

I want to compile a list of all discounts that were applied to cash payments in the same format that I have on the `Discounts` sheet, right now i'm using this formula but it's not giving me the results i'm looking for:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(CashPayments!A3:A,{Discounts!B5:N,Discounts!A5:N},{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},TRUE))`

End result I'm looking for is the total Discounted $ amount per user that was applied to cash payments.
[image: Discounts sheet, I'd like this narrowed down to Discounts on Cash Payments]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired results using COUNTIF

`=IF(COUNTIF(CashPayments!$A$3:$A,$B1412),$F1412,"Non-Cash Payment")`